# Relation between CAPM and Portfolio Theory

Tags: portfolio, modern-portfolio-theory, capm

can any of you explain to me in simple terms how CAPM and portfolio theory are related to each other? To my understanding: Portfolio theory helps to select the "right" stocks under risk/return aspects and shows the effect of diversification. It shows that some portfolio compositions might be inefficient compared to others. Further, if one allows risk-free investments in addition to a portfolio, this results in the tangent portfolio as an efficient portfolio, which then becomes the market portfolio in CAPM. The CAPM is than used to determine the expected return of a security, considering its risk premium. Unfortunately I don't geht how the portfolio theory and CAPM are related to each other. Is it basically, that Portfolio Theory refers to a Portfolio of assets and the CAPM takes the idea and uses it for individual assets?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Quite simply CAPM is the result of some very smart economists (Sharpe, Lintner, Treynor)  asking the question: what happens in the marketplace if everyone uses the concepts of Portfolio theory (diversification, using mean and variance as criteria)  to manage their portfolio? What general equilibrium would result in a  perfect competitive market? So CAPM is an economic theory while MPT is a theory of individual decision making.

Comment: In PT the expected returns are given exogenously, in CAPM they can be computed from the theory (although, disappointingly, the computed results don't seem to match the empirical reality very well).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. I guess what confuses me is that mostly CAPM is referred to as a model that tells you how much return you have to expect from an individual security, while CAPM is an economic theory which is about the market as a whole.